# Issue with UIDocumentInteractionController iOS11 beta 4

Tags: ios11

I have a set of apps (e.g `AppA` and `AppB`). Lets say `AppA` programmatically sends a zip file to another app. On `AppA` `UIDocumentInteractionController` popover is displayed with **Copy to AppB** icon.

Once I choose `AppB` it sends the zip file to `AppB`. The file gets copied in required folder of tht `AppB` and the control navigates back to `AppA`.
So this functionality works perfectly fine on iOS 10.3.3.

However, on iOS 11 beta 2 and now on beta 4 too, this feature does not work. The document controller popover opens and then it says unable to load on the top. Even if I click the Copy to AppB icon to copy, it does not do anything. In previous versions I was not getting this *Unable to load* message on the UIDocumentInteractionController popover on top as highlighted in the image below

[Doc controller image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2oVk.png)

I have checked that the plist of both apps has the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`

Update 1:

While debugging all the delegate methods do get called viz., `willBeginSendingToApplication` and `didEndSendingToApplication`. When I sending this file to another application, I dismiss the`docContoller`. So even the `documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOpenInMenu` also gets called.

So still the `docController` dismisses and activity indicator *Sending load to application* is displayed and remains there forever. The `AppB` is not launched.

**New findings on iOS 11 beta 5**

The **Unable to Load** message on the `UIDocumentInteractionController` is no more present. However, on click of the icon `AppB` the problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem occur where the file to be copied is in the app bundle.  With iOS 10 it worked just fine direct from the bundle.

In iOS 11 a file located in the app bundle will copy fine to Apple's own apps but not to third party apps.  Copying the file from the bundle to the tmp folder, then using that file and everything works.